# Download a Kaggle Dataset

Tags: python, json, kaggle

I would like to download a Kaggle Dataset. I generated the Kaggle.json file, but unfortunately I don't have a drive (I can't use it). Is there any option to generate the username and token in directly in the code?
For example I tried this

```
x =  '{"username":"<USERNAME>","key":"<TOKEN>"}'
y = json.loads(x)
api = KaggleApi(y)
api.authenticate()
files = api.competition_download_files("two-sigma-financial-news")
```

The error is

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-237de0539a08> in <module>()
          1 api = KaggleApi(y)
    ----> 2 api.authenticate()
          3 files = api.competition_download_files("two-sigma-financial-news")
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py in authenticate(self)
        164                 raise IOError('Could not find {}. Make sure it\'s located in'
        165                               ' {}. Or use the environment method.'.format(
    --> 166                                   self.config_file, self.config_dir))
        167 
        168         # Step 3: load into configuration!
    
        OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.
```

But it isn't right. May someone could help me plase? I'm using Colab, but I don't want to store the JSON file in my Google Drive. Is there any option to generate the JSON file directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this post helps: https://www.kaggle.com/general/51898
it links to this script:

```py
# Info on how to get your api key (kaggle.json) here: https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#api-credentials
!pip install kaggle
api_token = {"username":"USERNAME","key":"API_KEY"}
import json
import zipfile
import os
with open('/content/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)
!chmod 600 /content/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle config path -p /content
!kaggle competitions download -c jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge
os.chdir('/content/competitions/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge')
for file in os.listdir():
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()
```

from: https://gist.github.com/jayspeidell/d10b84b8d3da52df723beacc5b15cb27